# Add Intershop CIC system events programmatically

Tags: events, system, intershop

Is there a way I can add system events to the Intershop Commerce Insight programmatically? A REST API or something similar would be awesome. I can only find the manual way over the web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make this easier for you ;)

https://support.intershop.de/kb/index.php/Display/Z21263#Guide-UsingIntershopCommerceInsightWebServices-UsingtheICIEventsWebService